# TypeError: can't pickle dict_keys objects calling mdl.solve() in cplex

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, cplex

I have an OR problem and using an academic version of cplex library in the jupyter notebook by python 3.6.
When I am calling the following command I get an error:
command:

```
solution=mdl.solve(log_output=True)
```

error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle dict_keys objects
```

when I removed (log_output=True) everything works just fine, but I need the detailed output.

Since this is a crossed reference question, I would rather not repeat myself and confuse other people. The reason to ask here is that different scholars are attending these two reference webpages. 
https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/issues/14
If I find my answer in stackoverflow I will share the solution procedure here and on github.

Comment: Can you please add the full backtrace of the error as well as your full Python code (the cross-linked question does not contain everything to reproduce the problem). Please also include the version of `docplex` you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel Junglas,
My question has been answered in the above-mentioned link.
https://pypi.org/project/docplex/2.10.150/

Comment: Unless you plan on deleting this question, it would be nice if you would [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here in stackoverflow so that others can see that it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the solution found in the external link: the problem is fixed in [docplex ersion 2.10.150](https://pypi.org/project/docplex/2.10.150/). Upgrading to that version fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Junglas mentioned there were some inconsistencies between the two version of docplex toolbox and cplex 12.9 academic version I was using. A member of IBM team noticed the problem and updated the docplex version. And the lastest version up to date 07/08/2019 is here https://pypi.org/project/docplex/2.10.150/.
Many thanks to IBM Team.